# Export Chart Using PhantomJS From WebServer

Tags: highcharts

Using HighCharts 3.x and PhantomJS as a webserver how can I send in the correct JSON string when a user clicks on the export button on the webpage? Following along with the documentation [here](http://docs.highcharts.com/#render-charts-on-the-server) I can see how to set up PhantomJS as a standalone webserver. I can send in a curl command to export sample charts. I want to now use this method to send requests for an export using a website that is hosting a chart such that when the user clicks on export it goes out to the PhantomJS url/port and sends it the JSON of the chart to be exported. I have it set up currently to use my testing server but when I click to export the chart I get the following error:

> Failed rendering:  SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string

This makes sense because the export options, to the best of my knowledge, send out an SVG string. How to make it send the HighCharts JSON string instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file download isn´t supported by PhantomJS.. That's why the phantomjs export-module is returning a 64 bit string representation of a image. So, in the end this isn't going to work out of the box.

You get the `Unable to Parse JSON` error because the PhantomJS script is expecting this format `{infile: ... , outfile: ...}` and standard export functionality of Highcharts is sending a POST request with post parameters.

Comment: Ah, OK. So we still need to use the java implementation to get the web-server based export. I got all excited when it said you could start phatnomJS as a webserver.

Comment: @gert Is that correct? The PhantomJS web server does not work as described, and we need to use the Java implementation?